# Entity Framework 4 ste delete foreign key relationship

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF4 and STE w/ Silverlight.

I'm having trouble deleting child records from my primary entity. For some reason I can remove child entities if their foreign key to my primary entity is part of their Primary Key.

But if it's not, they don't get removed.

I believe these posts explains it:
http://mocella.blogspot.com/2010/01/entity-framework-v4-object-graph.html

http://blogs.msdn.com/dsimmons/archive/2010/01/31/deleting-foreign-key-relationships-in-ef4.aspx

My question is how how do I remove a child record who's foreign key is not part of its primary key in Silverlight where I don't have access to a DeleteObject() function?

Comment: Can you show the code you're presently using and describe the expected vs. actual behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was trying to do:

```
PrimaryEntity.Children.Remove(itemToDelete);
```

But what I had to do to make it work was:

```
itemToDelete.MarkAsDeleted();
```